# HTML5 getElementById doesn't work using Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I am sure that in the past I accessed the audio element, and I know it is a valid way of using it. But I cannot find out why this time it just doesn't work !!! what am I doing wrong? (I am using firefox)

what is wrong with calling the following code?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<!-- var audio = new Audio(); audio.src = 'sounds/audio1_1.mp3'; audio.controls = true; audio.loop = true; audio.autoplay = true; -->
var audioElement_theme;
audioElement_theme = document.getElementById("audio1_1");
audioElement_theme.play();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="audio1_1"><source src="sounds/audio1_1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><source src="sounds/audio1_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I change:

```
audioElement_theme = document.getElementById("audio1_1");
audioElement_theme.play();
```

to:

```
var audio = new Audio(); 
audio.src = 'sounds/audio1_1.mp3'; 
audio.controls = true; 
audio.loop = true; 
audio.autoplay = true;
```

It works !!!

Answer (score 2):

The element doesn't exist at the time you try to get it by its id.

Move the script so it is after the audio element.

---

You also have an HTML comment inside the the script. That might also interfere.

A JavaScript comment looks:

```
// like this
```

or

```
/* like this */
```

Comment: No, HTML comments are supported by the popular JS engines (even though that's not required by the standard).

Answer (score 0):

YOur code works, I tested it. When you run your current code it will give you an error in console windows like "Can not read property .paly() of null" so move your Script after audio tag. So just move your code after  tag.

Comment: I mean code is absolutely correct but it is placed at wrong place.